# Vector becomes empty after returning from a function

Tags: c++, function, vector, return, tuples

I am returning a vector from a function that is called inside main(). But when I access the returned vector in the main, it becomes empty where the `vector_variable.size() = 0`.

I have tried printing the elements and the size of this vector_variable inside the function where it is populated, it works fine and gives me the desired result. Only when I access it after returning from the function, it becomes empty. I feel like there is a memory access error, but I am not sure

```
inline std::tuple<cv::Mat,  std::vector<float>> 
computeCountVector( const cv::Mat &cloud) {

  std::vector<float> valid_id_vec;

  for (std::int32_t point_index{0}; point_index<1000; ++point_index) { 

      //z is already initialized
      const auto col = std::round(cloud.at<float>(point_index, 0) / z);  
      valid_id_vec.push_back(col);
      cloud.at<float>(point_index, 0)  *= 2.5;
  }
  // Skipping the rest of the code to retain clarity and reliablity
  std::cout<<"\n Size of the vec inside the function :"<<valid_id_vec.size();

  //Returning the vector
  return std::make_tuple(cloud, valid_id_vec);
}

//Inside main
void main() {

    //Delcarations
    std::vector<float> col_vec;

    //Fucntion call that returns the vector
    std::tie(cloud, col_vec) = computeCountVector(cloud); //cloud variable is computed before this piece of code
    std::cout<<"\n SIZE inside the main(): "<<col_vec.size();
}
```

This is my output:

```
Size of the vec inside the function : 1000
SIZE inside the main(): 0
```

Comment: You missed a "," in your tie call, but I guess it's a copy paste mistake

Comment: Nothing is really jumping out at me.  Can you provide a [mre]?

Comment: Inside the function you're printing `valid_col_vec.size()`, is that a typo?

Comment: I dislike abbreviated code, too often the abbreviation cuts the real error (and introduces new ones). Try and produce a genuine minimal reproducable example. Unlike many people who post here, it seems you have the skills to do it.

Comment: `void main()` is invalid C++, the compiler should complain. Of the mainstream compilers, only MSVC accepts this code at all; you should always use the option `/permissive-` here.

Comment: At AdrienGivry, john, user4581301, Konrad Rudolph - Thanks for correcting the typo. To avoid readability issues, I cut down this huge code into chunks. I also introduced the main(). I will add a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: I was wondering if there are any possible memory issues with the way I am returning these STL classes. Or what would be a better way to return this vector back to the original function?

Comment: Can you reproduce this with a much simpler example, [like this one](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/bf43274c4b5d2d71) ? Because I cannot.

Comment: I was not able to reproduce.  I used `int` as `cv::Mat`.  Could `cv::Mat` be messing things up for the tuple and tie?

Comment: if instead of using `std::tie`, you assign the result of `computeCloudVector` to a tuple and check that, does it still happen? Also, out of curiosity, why not just pass one or both variables by reference and not return a tuple at all

Comment: I am also unable to reproduce this. I can only think of either cloud is modifying the vector somehow or there's an issue in the code that was cut out.
Side note that you could also change the function signature to `inline std::vector<float>computeCountVector( cv::Mat &cloud)` (removing the const) so you can modify cloud directly, and get rid of the tuple altogether.

Comment: You take `const cv::Mat &cloud` as a parameter, but then the function modifies cloud. You don't get an error?